# Restamping CAdES-A using Digital Signature Service from joinup.ec.europa.eu.

Tags: java, timestamp, digital-signature, archive

I have a stupid question, about restamping using joinup.ec.europa.eu project for CAdES Archival digital signature .

My detaliled report looks like this:

...

```
<TimestampValidationData>

<Signature Id="id-338d625629abaef940d8fd662e4a5ca0">

<Timestamp Id="a86732870900b61d74c01edf6fd1b9f3e0f195a315c832b9b7d2f5e17576fc5a" Type="SIGNATURE_TIMESTAMP"></Timestamp>

<Timestamp Id="c03587eb0d393616bb0124956c8a0746c1a4f0573721b60c605935e0ac2c5935" Type="ARCHIVE_TIMESTAMP"></Timestamp>

</Signature>

</TimestampValidationData>
```

...

My questions is how do I add more ARCHIVE_TIMESTAMP on my signature?

I used example from cookbook for detached signature, using LTA form.